# Expectation of function of random variables (example Euclidean distance)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

How the expectation value of a nonlinear transform of normal distributed variables can be approximated by Mathematica in case there is no analytical solution?

Let's take the Euclidian distance of 2 points in $\mathbb{R^3}$ as an example. The variables $p0,...,p5$ shall be the expectation values of the point coordinates. The distributions are independent and identical with equal variance $s^2$.

Below is the code where an approximated solution in dependence of $p0,...,p5$ and $s$ shall be found:

```
Expectation[
 Sqrt[(x0 - x1)^2 + (x2 - x3)^2 + (x4 - x5)^2],
 {
  x0 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p0, s^2],
  x1 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p1, s^2],
  x2 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p2, s^2],
  x3 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p3, s^2],
  x4 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p4, s^2],
  x5 \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[p5, s^2]
  }]
```

Comment: Is `p0, p1,...` and `s` not known?

Comment: These are variables.

Comment: This is rather math than Mathematica. Because the difference of two independent normal distributions is  a normal distribution too, you deal with the mean of a noncentalchisquare distribution( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NoncentralChiSquareDistribution.html ).

Comment: The noncentral chi distribution has no closed solution for the expectation value. The Laguerre function makes trouble. For what is Mathematica useful if not for math?

Comment: Your claim "The noncentral cchi distribution has no closed solution for the expectation value" is not exact Its mean is expressed it terms of the Laguerre function (see the above linked  Wiki article) so this is an analytic expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). MMA deals with Laguerre functions. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need

Comment: Yes in this special case the Laguerre function could be a try and we are already at the brink of analytical solutions. So it was a bad example. Actually I am looking for an approximated solution to solve in general functions of random variables that have no analytical solution.

Comment: Btw. $LaguerreL[n,a,x]$ gives no general expression for the variable $x$ if $n=a=1/2$ as needed.

Comment: No, L[1/2,1/2,x] is not expressed through other special and elementary  functions. However, we can built its plot, calculate LaguerreL[1/2, 1/2, 2.3]  in MMA and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From @user64494 's comments and the mentioned [Wiki page][1] the expectation of

$$\sqrt{(x_0-x_1)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_4-x_5)^2}$$

will be

$$\sqrt{\pi } \sigma  L_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(-\frac{L^2}{4 \sigma ^2}\right)$$

or in *Wolfram Language*

```
σ Sqrt[π]*LaguerreL[1/2, 1/2, -L^2/(4 σ^2)]
```

where I've substituted the more commonly used $\sigma$ for $s$ and

```
L = Sqrt[(p0 - p1)^2 + (p2 - p3)^2 + (p4 - p5)^2]
```

While this is an exact result the OP has the concern that few programming languages have adequate approximations (if they have an approximation at all) of the `LaguerreL` function.

Fortunately, there is a simplification in this case.

```
σ Sqrt[π]*LaguerreL[1/2, 1/2, -L^2/(4 σ^2)] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
```

results in

$$\left(\frac{2 \sigma ^2}{L}+L\right) \text{erf}\left(\frac{L}{2 \sigma }\right)+\frac{2 \sigma  e^{-\frac{L^2}{4 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}$$

or

```
(2 E^(-(L^2/(4 σ^2))) σ)/Sqrt[π] + (L + (2 σ^2)/L) Erf[L/(2 σ)]
```

Most languages (even Excel) have an `Erf` function (or an equivalent) readily available.

(Again, this is not an approximation as requested.  If the OP can present an example where there isn't an exact solution, then approximation approach can be better targeted.  My reasoning for this is that such approximations depend on the functions being approximated and the range of values for which the approximation is desired to work.  Being specific for a needed approximation would likely get better answers.)

Comment: Please look here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445185/expectation-of-function-of-normal-distributed-variables

Comment: Can Mathematica help if the solution is not known?

Comment: Certainly.  Finding the mean after using `Series` on the random variable for an approximation (or if one is lucky that can find the exact mean).  Or if there are few enough parameters, use numerical integration for a wide range of parameters and then see if there is a function of the parameters that will predict the mean.  And setting a specific value for each parameter and then taking the mean of lots of random samples.  The latter is easily programmed in most languages.

Comment: If $\sigma=0.001$ and L is in the range [0,1] then z is in the range [0,-250000]. There is no practical series expansion for this range. One needs an expansion in dependence of $u$, however this is not calculated: $Series[LaguerreL[1/2, 1/2, z], {z, u, 1}]=LaguerreL[1/2,1/2,u]-LaguerreL[-(1/2),3/2,u] (z-u)+O[z-u]^2$

Comment: Not true.  I just stumbled across this:  `FunctionExpand[LaguerreL[1/2, 1/2, -z]] // FullSimplify` results in $\frac{(2 z+1) \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{z}}+\frac{2 e^{-z}}{\pi }$.  I'll add that into my answer.

Comment: With this answer I am satisfied. There are good and simple calculatable approximations for the error function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Numerical_approximations

Regarding the example where an approximation is needed but no solution exists I refer to the function of the cross product here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445185/expectation-of-cross-product-of-normal-distributed-variables

Answer (score -3):

There are simpler solutions for special cases.

### Definitions

$x_i=\mathcal{N}(p_i,\sigma^2)_{i=1...6}$ are 6 independent normal distributed random variates with expectations $p_i$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (this replaces  $s^2$ from the original post).

The random variables are transformed by the Euclidian distance function $$L(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=\sqrt{(x_0 - x_1)^2 + (x_2 - x_3)^2 + (x_4 - x_5)^2}$$ The distance of the expected values is $$L(p_0,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5)=L_p=\sqrt{(p_0 - p_1)^2 + (p_2 - p_3)^2 + (p_4 - p_5)^2}$$

The expected value of $L$ is $\mathbb{E}[L]$.

### Results

For following 2 cases simpler expressions of approximated expectations $\mathbb{E_1}[L], \mathbb{E_2}[L] $ are:

$$\frac{\sigma}{L_p} \approx 0 \hspace{2mm} \rightarrow \hspace{2mm} \mathbb{E_1}[L] =\sqrt{L_p^2+6\sigma^2} \approx \mathbb{E}[L] $$

$$\frac{L_p}{\sigma} \approx 0 \hspace{2mm} \rightarrow \hspace{2mm} \mathbb{E_2}[L]=\frac{4\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}\approx \mathbb{E}[L] $$

### Derivations

The distribution $$L'(x_i)=\left(\frac{x_0 - x_1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_2 - x_3}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_4 - x_5}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2$$
is a noncentral chi square distribution with $k=3$ degrees of freedom and the noncentrality parameter is

$$\lambda=L'(p_i)=\left(\frac{p_0 - p_1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{p_2 - p_3}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{p_4 - p_5}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2=\left(\frac{L_p}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2$$

The expectation value of a noncentral chi square distribution is

$$\mathbb{E}[L']=\lambda+k$$

If  $\frac{\sigma}{L_p}\approx 0 $ then $L' \approx \lambda$ and using the approximation
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{\lambda+\delta_i}\approx \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda+\delta_i)} \hspace{3mm}\text{for}\hspace{3mm} |\delta_i|\ll \lambda $$

$\mathbb{E}[L]$ is approximated by

$$\frac{\mathbb{E_1}[L]}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}=\mathbb{E_1}\left[\sqrt{L'}\right]\approx \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[L']}$$
and it follows
$$\mathbb{E_1}[L] =\sqrt{L_p^2+6\sigma^2}$$

If  $\frac{L_p}{\sigma}\approx 0 $ then $\lambda\approx 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[L]$ is approximated by the expectation of a chi distribution

$$\frac{\mathbb{E_2}[L]}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\approx\sqrt{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}=2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
It follows
$$\mathbb{E_2}[L]=\frac{4\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

It holds $\mathbb{E_1}[L] \ge \mathbb{E}[L] \ge \mathbb{E_2}[L] $.

### Examples

If the values of $L_p$ and $\sigma$ are in the proper ratio then the approximations are quite close to the exact solutions. This is seen below where the approximate and exact solutions are compared. The example coordinates from another post $p_i=(1,0,2,0,3,0)$ are used, $L_p=\sqrt{14}\approx 3.74$.

- $\sigma=0.02, \frac{\sigma}{L_p}\approx 0$

$\small \mathbb{E_1}[L]=3.7419781$

$\small\mathbb{E}[L]=3.7418712$

- $\sigma=200, \frac{L_p}{\sigma}\approx 0$

$\small\mathbb{E_2}[L]=451.35167$

$\small\mathbb{E}[L]=451.36483$

- $\sigma=2 \approx L_p $

$\small\mathbb{E_1}[L]=6.1644140$

$\small\mathbb{E_2}[L]=4.5135167$

$\small\mathbb{E}[L]=5.7275959$

### Motivation

Why do we need these approximations?
The exact solutions require calculation of the mean of a noncentral chi distribution that practically means calculation of a generalized Laguerre function that is related to Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function. In Mathematica the functions $Hypergeometric1F1[a,b,z]$ with $a=-\frac{1}{2}, b=\frac{3}{2}$ or $LaguerreL[n,k,z]$ with $n=k=\frac{1}{2}$ can be used, $z$ has negative real part. There might be problems if you try to translate your code into another languange. Such special functions are not available in all software packages or supported only for $a,b,n,k\in \mathbb{N}$. Special treatment regarding numerical stability is needed if you write your own routine. So the given approximations may help in some cases.

Comment: The statement $\frac{\sigma}{L} \approx 0 $ makes no sense: its LHS is a random variable, whereas its RHS is a number. Also the relation  $ \approx $ is not defined.

Comment: The statement after edit $\frac{\sigma}{L(p_i)} \approx 0  $ makes no sense because of the same reasons.

Comment: This answer does not deal with Mathematica at all. Next, it looks like a fake: several edits in the same formula, no definitions, no calculations, and no references.

Comment: The answer was refurbished and includes now proofs and motivation.

Comment: Up to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution , $$L'(x_i)=\left(\frac{x_0 - x_1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_2 - x_3}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x_4 - x_5}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)^2 $$ is not a noncentral chi distribution: there is no square root. Also there is $x_i$ in the LHS, but there is no $x_i$ in the RHS.

Comment: Are there particular packages that you need to use that don't have such functions?  R, MATLAB, python, and even Excel have 1F1 functions.  But that begs the question:  How is this related to this forum about *Mathematica*?

Comment: One can move it to another forum.

Comment: There are programs that do not support the full parameter range of such functions, e.g. IDL. Mostly they only support integer parameter. And one cannot rely on Mathematica if one needs to transfer a function to another software platform. Then Mathematica can only be used for testing. Furthermore the approximative formulas can be quite faster calculated even with Mathematica in case speed is needed.
The last comment of user64494 is wrong.

Comment: Actually my initial intention of my question was to know if Mathematica can help to find a functional expression of an approximate solution. I wanted to avoid functions that are defined by a limit process. These are hard to export. So the question is  deeply related to Mathematica. Finally I solved the problem on my own.